# SQL SELECT QUERY RELATION TABLES

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm a little lost with sql. I'm trying to get values of referenced tables, and i have to go throught 6 tables but i'm not getting any result. This is my code:

```
SELECT v.VEHICLEPLATE, p.NAME
  FROM ITV i, VEHICLE v, BUYS b, PERSON p, CENTER c, WORKER w
  WHERE
   w.NICK = 'PEPE' AND
   c.ID = w.CENTERID AND
   v.VEHICLEPLATE = i.VEHICLEPLATE AND
   v.VEHICLEPLATE = b.VEHICLEPLATE AND
   p.ID = b.PERSON;
```

I want to get all the records in ITV where PEPE works.

Someone can help or orient me please?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  PLease read [ask] and show table schema, and sample data, and expected output

Answer (score 1):

Use explicit joins for your tables instead of implicit, like this:

```
SELECT v.VEHICLEPLATE, p.NAME
FROM ITV i
INNER JOIN VEHICLE v ON v.VEHICLEPLATE = i.VEHICLEPLATE
INNER JOIN BUYS b ON v.VEHICLEPLATE = b.VEHICLEPLATE
INNER JOIN PERSON p ON p.ID = b.PERSON
INNER JOIN CENTER c --Need join condition here
INNER JOIN WORKER w ON c.ID = w.CENTERID
WHERE w.NICK = 'PEPE';
```

It's a lot easier to read, and the implicit style you have in your question is depreciated.

Now you can see you are missing your join condition for `INNER JOIN CENTER C`.  You may have further issues but start here and if it still isn't right, provide us with your current results and your expected results.